# How to change PyQt5 QComboBox style

Tags: css, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox

Does anyone know how to change that drop list style? The scroll bar, selected item color, border etc.
[image: combo box]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

edit style sheet.

example:

```
background-color: rgb(231, 230, 234); 
border-radius: 7px;
padding: 8px;
```